# How to access google calendar of logged in users in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, calendar

I want to access the google calendar of any user who logged in or register in wordpress website.
But I am able to access only one calendar events that is registered.

I've searching many plugin and also create one custom plugin but all those plugins allows us to access only registered user's calendar who make its calendar public. My requirement is when any person logged in or register in website then they can able to see its own calendar with events
Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

this plugin can help you [user-registration](https://wpeverest.com/wordpress-plugins/user-registration/)
The best part of this plugin is that it automatically creates a user profile account for your users.